# What does MessageDigest.update(byte[]) do?

Tags: java, android, hash, salt, message-digest

What exactly does this do? I tried to look it up but didn't find anything.

Reason for asking is I want to incorporate a SALT `byte[]` into a value which is then hashed. So should it be done like this (Pseudo code):

```
MessageDigest.update(SALT);
MessageDigest.update(value);
digestValue = MessageDigest.digest();
// Where SALT, value and digestValue are array bytes, byte[]
```

Does this add both `SALT` and `value` to the final digest or should I combine both variables into one and then `update` it once?

I couldn't find an answer for this in any documentation, any clarification would be appreciated.

Thank you, cheers.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Its the right way to create a salted digest of a value.

Comment: Did you look at [the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)?

Comment: @Qwerky Thank you for confirming :)

Comment: @Jesper Unfortunately that documentation and all of the other ones that I found, don't explain much.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MessageDigest` is statefull, calls of `MessageDigest.update(byte[] input)` accumulate digest updates until we call `MessageDigest.digest`. Run this test to make sure:

```
    MessageDigest md1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md1.update(new byte[] {1, 2});
    md1.update(new byte[] {3, 4});
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(md1.digest()));

    MessageDigest md2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md2.update(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4});
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(md2.digest()));
```

output

```
[8, -42, -64, 90, 33, 81, 42, 121, -95, -33, -21, -99, 42, -113, 38, 47]
[8, -42, -64, 90, 33, 81, 42, 121, -95, -33, -21, -99, 42, -113, 38, 47]
```

Comment: Appreciate the elaborated explanation, follow up question: so all what `update` does is concatenate the arrays together, nothing else special?

Comment: When we give a MessageDigest an array it simply iterates over this array and updates digest by byte